# Hammer JS events stop by themselves

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, createjs, hammer.js

I have a problem with Hammer JS. I have implemented it with CreateJS and used a global DOM element to latch onto and then created a manager to fire the events down the chain into CreateJS, the events for pinch and rotate are being fired and works 100% on Safari and iOS Safari, the problem i am having is that on Chrome the pinch and rotate events never fully work and then suddenly stop, i have an example [here](http://creativewax.co.uk/private/emoticats/app.html#) with log outputs to show whats happening, randomly even though you are still pinching or rotating, the cancel event seems to fire by itself ? on a desktop use Shift to trigger the second touch

Comment: Can you recreate this issue with a code sample please.

Comment: ill split it out simpler into a code snippet